# In form numberpad C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I would like to add an in form numberpad to my form to make the program more touch friendly. I have multiple text boxes on this form that change focus when the enter key is pressed.

I tried SendKeys.Send("#"), but when I click the button it just changes focus to the button and does nothing inside the text box I was trying to type in.

Is there a guide or something for this? I have looked and all I can find are on screen keyboards that work outside of the form, but not inside.

Comment: Why don't make it so that it appends the pressed buttons value to the textbox contents instead. I.e press the button "1" and then it appends that to the existing values in the textbox?

Comment: On-screen keyboards don't use buttons.  They only *look* like buttons, pretty simple to emulate with a bitmap.  Graphics.DrawImage() and PictureBox solve your problem, you just need to add the mouse hit testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding a little bit on the idea from Hans Passant you could use this as a starting point.

#### Form

In your form add the textboxes you need and a [PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx). The picturebox will have an image with the characters your users need to be able to type.

Set the property [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx) to an [image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrnbO.png) (browse for it) (or create your own)
Set the property [`SizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`AutoSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) so the complete picture is shown.

Next goto the events and add an eventhandler for  [`MouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx).

#### Code

Add the following code to the handler:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // how many rows and columns do we have
    // in the picture used
    const int maxrows = 4;
    const int maxcols = 3;

    // based on each position (numbered from left to right, top to bottom)
    // what character do we want to add the textbox 
    var chars = new [] {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '+', '0', '-'};
       
    // on which row and col is clicked, based on the mouse event
    // which hold the X and Y value of the coordinates relative to 
    // the control.
    var  row = (e.Y * maxrows) / this.pictureBox1.Height;
    var col = (e.X * maxcols) / this.pictureBox1.Width;
       
    // calculate the position in the char array
    var scancode = row * maxcols + col;
            
    // if the active control is a TextBox ...
    if (this.ActiveControl is TextBox)
    {
        // ... add the char to the Text.
        // add error and bounds checking as well as 
        // handling of special chars like delete/backspace/left/right
        // if added and needed
        this.ActiveControl.Text += chars[scancode];
    }
}
```

The code is I think self explanatory. Keep in mind that no error checking whatsoever is being done here.

#### Result

This is what the end result will look like:

[image: numpad entering textboxes]

Comment: Okay, I followed the instructions, but the picture is blank. When I click on it it works as intended, but I can't see what number I'm clicking. Did I miss something? Also the default autosize is a bit small, is there a way to increase it? Thank you so much for your help. Edit: I am dumb. I missed the picture file you provided. Sorry for being dense.

Comment: Did you add the Image to the image property of the PictureBox?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I noticed that part right after I made the comment. But is there a way to set one of the areas to the enter key? That's the only thing that's missing that I need.

Comment: Sure, you could add before the `this.ActiveControl.Text += chars[scancode];` an `if (scancode == 11) {this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true,true); return; };`  see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: in this example the - (the right bottom key) would become enter. I didn't try this because I don't have a dev box available at the moment so the code comes without guarantees...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your help. The only thing wrong with that code was a missing = sign. it should be `if (scancode == 11) {this.SelectNextControl(this.ActiveControl, true, true, true,true); return; };`         Works great! Exactly what I needed. You have been immensely helpful.