# how to make keyboard in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, .net-3.5

I need keyboard functionality in windows form application I am using

```
private void btnW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCategory.Text += btnW.Text;      
}
```

[image]

But I need it for multiple `textbox` like if focused on `textbox1` it will add `text` in `textbox1` an if `TextBox2` focused keyboard `button` will effect on `TextBox2` only.

like real keyboard functionality
in .Net 3.5 version

seen in screen shoots

Comment: This should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843865/in-form-numberpad-c-sharp/31860907#31860907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
object obj;
private void btnW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        (obj as TextBox).Text += btnW.Text;
    }
}
private void txtCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    obj = txtCategory;
}
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    obj = textBox1;
}
```

Comment: this is perfect but sorry for so late

Answer (score 0):

First find the focussed textbox, then set the text in that box:

```
private void btnW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Func<Control, TextBox> FindFocusedTextBox(Control control)
    {
        var container = this as IContainerControl;
        while (container != null)
        {
            control = container.ActiveControl;
            container = control as IContainerControl;
        }
        return control as TextBox;
    }

    var focussedTextBox = FindFocusedTextBox(this);
    if(focussedTextBox != null)
        focussedTextBox.Text += btnW.Text;
}
```

Footnote: Finding the focus was derived from: [What is the preferred way to find focused control in WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435433/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-find-focused-control-in-winforms-app)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you an option. Hope that it will help you

Declare a global TextBoxObject in the page and assign the textbox that is currently focused to this object. there will be an event handler let it be `btnW_Click` for all buttons. then you can add text to the focused textbox. See the code for this:

```
TextBox TextBoxObject; // this will be global

// Event handler for all button
private void btnW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(TextBoxObject!=null)
   {
      TextBoxObject.Text += btnW.Text;   // This will add the character at the end of the current text
      // if you want to Add at the current position means use like this
        int currentIndex = TextBoxObject.SelectionStart;
      TextBoxObject.Text = TextBoxObject.Text.Insert(currentIndex, btnW.Text);
   }
}
```

You have to assign focus to the text box by using following code:

```
private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxObject = textBox1;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It will helpful for you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow
{    
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    TextBox txtName; 
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName = textBox1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName != null)
        {
            txtName.Text += button1.Text;                                
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName != null)
        {
            txtName.Text += button2.Text;             
        }
    }
    private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName = textBox2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @zubair Ahmad Please Go through the updated coding :))))